# Authenticating via oAUTH with providers using Phonegap for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, oauth, cordova

We are currently working on the finishing touches of an application which uses Phonegap and have hit some issues with the Blackberry port.

So far, we've been reviewing the content available online and can't find a really finale answer to this. Seems like the "right" way to make and oauth authentication process for either Twitter, Facebook or Foursquare would be to use the ChildBrowser plugin, instantiate a window and then use that to handle the process.

Rightly so, there seems to be a lack of a ChildBrowser plugin for Blackberry. We've been looking so far at a couple of private projects on Github that look like they build/use that capability but we are not sure on how to control the created window.

Most (or all?) of those plugins refer to invoking the native Blackberry browser to handle the URLS, but then how would be manage to work on the callbacks, get the tokens and close the windows since it's another process.

For example, we have this concept code:

```
function openWindow() {
  if (typeof blackberry !== 'undefined') {
    app_id = SOMETHING_HERE;
    redirect = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorizeclient_id='+app_id+'&redirect_uri='+redirect+'&display=touch&scope=publish_stream';
    var args = new blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments(url);
    blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_BROWSER, args);
            }
        }
```

Which works for opening the URL, but that's it. Is there a way to get a handle on the window and inject some listener to events? What should be our correct approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not PhoneGap user, but we did have to handle a very similar scenario - native app invokes the mobile browser to prompt the oAuth flow and then be able to handle a callback to the aative app.

This is possible on the BlackBerry using the BrowserContentProviderRegistry API. You can register your app to be invoked whenever a particular MIME type is returned to the browser. Sounds complicated but its fairly straightforward when all the pieces are in play.

Here is the rough flow -

1. Native app invokes browser to the oAuth page. This is part is easy and seems like you got this part.
2. The oAuth redirect needs to go to a URL that you can control. Something like http://mycompany.com/oAuthRedirectHandler.asp.
3. The oAuthRedirectorHandler.asp has simple code like this (we chose classic ASP but this can be done in PHP or any language, you can also ignore the Android block below) -

   ```
   <html><body>
   <h1>Redirect page</h1> 
   If you are not re-directed, please open the application manually.  
   <% strUA = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT") 
   if (InStr(strUA, "BlackBerry")) then    
         Response.Write("Opening appplication on BlackBerry")  
         Response.ContentType="application/x-MyCustomApp" 
   elseif (InStr(strUA, "Android")) then   
         Response.Write("Opening appplication on Android")     
         Response.Redirect("MyCustomApp://mycompany.com") 
   end if %> 
   </body> </html>
   ```
4. In your BlackBerry code you want a new BrowserContentProvider like this -

   ```
   final class CustomBrowserProvider  extends BrowserContentProvider{ 
     String[] ACCEPT = new String[]{"application/x-MyCustomApp};
     String appName;

     CustomBrowserProvider(String appName){
       this.appName = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getModuleName();
       //cache this appName from the constructor in the invocation code below. 
     }

     public String[] getSupportedMimeTypes() { return ACCEPT;}
     public String[] getAccept(RenderingOptions context){return ACCEPT;}

     public BrowserContent getBrowserContent( BrowserContentProviderContext context) throws RenderingException {
       //this is where the callback happens
       //this is happening in a separate process, raise your main app here using the appName that got passed in
       //I dont have a sanitized ready to go sample to post here on how to do this, but not too complicated
       //as a hint use the ApplicationDescriptor and CodeModuleManager classes
       return null;
     }
   }
   ```
5. Now, in your application initialization, register this new BrowserPlugin like this -

   ```
    BrowserContentProviderRegistry converterRegistry = BrowserContentProviderRegistry.getInstance();
    converterRegistry.register(new CustomBrowserProvider());
   ```

Hope this helps. This has worked pretty well for us. The one downside we've had here is that when the user returns to the browser app, they are left with an empty page and there is no good way to close that in the BB.

Comment: Wow, this seems really interesting. Thanks a lot for your input! Will try and report back what I found out.